# Convert ASN1ObjectIdentifier to a readable String in Java

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle, asn.1

Okay this is probably a very stupid question but I'm using bouncycastle to parse issuer RDNS from a X509Certificate in the following way:

```
X500Name x500name = new JcaX509CertificateHolder(certificate).getIssuer();
RDN[] rdns = x500name.getRDNs();
for (int i = 0; i < rdns.length; ++i)
    String readableString = IETFUtils.valueToString(rdns[i].getFirst().getType())
    ...
```

... but all I get is some ASN1 OIDs.

So is there a way to convert ASN1ObjectIdentifier to a readable String like "CN", "OU" etc... instead of OIDs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500NameStyle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/asn1/x500/X500NameStyle.html) and its implementations.

```
X500NameStyle x500NameStyle = RFC4519Style.INSTANCE;

X500Name x500name = new JcaX509CertificateHolder( certificate ).getIssuer();
RDN[] rdns = x500name.getRDNs();
for ( RDN rdn : rdns ) {
    for ( AttributeTypeAndValue attribute : rdn.getTypesAndValues() ) {
        System.out.printf( "%s (%s) = %s%n",
                x500NameStyle.oidToDisplayName( attribute.getType() ),
                attribute.getType(),
                attribute.getValue()
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! That is exactly what I was looking for! Just out of curiosity, how did you find this? - Looking at the APIs I wasn't able to myself

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
X500Name x500name = new JcaX509CertificateHolder(certificate).getSubject();
```

will give you more detailed output than `getIssuer()`.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. From what I see in the [docs](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cert/X509CertificateHolder.html) you would be getting the information of a completely different object of the certificate: Subject vs Issuer.